# Creating R package

Tags: r, pdf, package

I have some troubles to create a R package. Everything is fine until the creation of the R manual. I installed everything but I cannot understand where is my problem. Here is my output of "R CMD check package".

```
Rcmd.exe build gigigi

checking for file 'gigigi/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
preparing 'gigigi':
checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
checking for empty or unneeded directories
building 'gigigi_1.0.tar.gz'


Rcmd.exe check gigigi_1.0.tar.gz

using log directory 'H://gigigi.Rcheck'
using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
using session charset: ISO8859-1
checking for file 'gigigi/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
checking extension type ... Package
this is package 'gigigi' version '1.0'
checking package namespace information ... OK
checking package dependencies ... OK
checking if this is a source package ... OK
checking if there is a namespace ... OK
checking for executable files ... OK
checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
checking for portable file names ... OK
checking whether package 'gigigi' can be installed ... OK
checking installed package size ... OK
checking package directory ... OK
checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
checking top-level files ... OK
checking for left-over files ... OK
checking index information ... OK
checking package subdirectories ... OK
checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
checking dependencies in R code ... OK
checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
checking replacement functions ... OK
checking foreign function calls ... OK
checking R code for possible problems ... OK
checking Rd files ... OK
checking Rd metadata ... OK
checking Rd cross-references ... OK
checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
checking Rd contents ... OK
checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
checking examples ... NONE
checking PDF version of manual ...Warning: running command  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-dir="C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpERDOHF/Rd2pdf6c2c7def4dbf" --no-clean -o  gigigi-manual.pdf  "H://gigigi.Rcheck/gigigi"' had status 1
WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-dir="C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpERDOHF/Rd2pdf6c2c2c7e6360" --no-clean --no-index -o  gigigi-manual.pdf  H://gigigi.Rcheck/gigigi' had status 1
Re-running with no redirection of stdout/stderr.
Hmm ... looks like a package
You may want to clean up by 'rm -rf C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpERDOHF/Rd2pdf6c2c53411284'
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
 pdflatex is not available
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
pdflatex is not available
Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-dir="C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpERDOHF/Rd2pdf6c2c53411284" --no-clean --no-index -o  gigigi-manual.pdf  H://gigigi.Rcheck/gigigi' had status 1

Exited with status 1.
```

I checked some solutions of the web, but I did not find answer:

```
Sys.which("pdflatex")
"C:\\PROGRA~2\\MIKTEX~1.9\\miktex\\bin\\pdflatex.exe"
```

Comment: "`pdflatex is not available`" causes all your problems. Just install it `install.packages("pdflatex", dependencies = T)`

Comment: Uh, no. pdflatex is not an R package. The issue is a recent change in miktex. Try using a different latex distribution, like texlive.

Comment: There are not any packages miktex or texlive. I tried texreg but it still does not work

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.r-bloggers.com/building-r-packages-missing-path-to-pdflatex/

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I have already checked it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a problem coping the file Rd.sty in a specific folder of MIKTEX.

Now the errors are different:

It looks like this package has a loading problem when not on .libPaths:
see the messages for details.

```
checking dependencies in R code ... OK

checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK

checking replacement functions ... OK

checking foreign function calls ... OK

checking R code for possible problems ... OK

checking Rd files ... OK

checking Rd metadata ... OK

checking Rd cross-references ... OK

checking for missing documentation entries ... OK

checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK

checking Rd \usage sections ... OK

checking Rd contents ... OK

checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK

checking contents of 'data' directory ... OK

checking data for non-ASCII characters ... OK

checking data for ASCII and uncompressed saves ... OK

checking examples ... OK

checking PDF version of manual ...Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-dir="C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWMICIY/Rd2pdf686c534f420d" --no-clean -o  KODAMA-manual.pdf  "H://KODAMA.Rcheck/KODAMA"' had status 1
WARNING

LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
```

This typically indicates Rd problems.

```
LaTeX errors found:

checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR

Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-
dir="C:/Users/scacciat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWMICIY/Rd2pdf686ccd610fa" --no-clean --no-index -o  KODAMA-manual.pdf  H://KODAMA.Rcheck/KODAMA' had status 1


Exited with status 1.
```